# why django models error keeps raising error?

Tags: django, database, model

I moved these to models to chat app

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="فرستنده")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="گیرنده", related_name="reciver")
    text = models.CharField("متن", max_length=500)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="موضوع")
    notification=models.OneToOneField(Notification,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name="message",null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "پیام"
        verbose_name_plural = "پیام ها"

class Response(Message):
   darkhast_sabt_sherekat = models.ForeignKey(SabteSherkat,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="responses")
```

After that, it raise an error saying the local id of Response crashed with message I made everything undo and this error keeps coming up

```
*
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, consultation, contenttypes, sessions, utilities, web
Running migrations:
  Applying web.0007_auto_20210815_0831...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 178, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 346, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_field=field)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 283, in _remake_table
    self.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s" % (
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
*
```

I deleted every **pycache** and my DB and even my virtualenv but this error keeps coming up!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `abstract = True` in Message models Meta class, maybe that's the issue.

```
class Message(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "پیام"
        verbose_name_plural = "پیام ها"
        abstract = True
```